# UIImageView with auto-layout and max size keeping aspect ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a `UIImageView` generated in source (programmatically). That `UIImageView` needs to have a max size, for both width and height. In this view, I load a image from URL and set after the download ends. I don't know previously, what is the size of the image, but I need to keep the aspect ratio and make the `UIImageView` with a size that maintains that aspect.

If the image is smaller, in one or both dimension, I want the `UIImageView` has the size necessary to maintain the aspect ratio without stretch the image.

I'll give two examples considering the max size for `UIImageView` with `250 X 350`.

**Example 1:**

The image size is `800 X 800`.
The size of `UIImageView` needs to be `250 X 250`.

**Example 2:**

The image size is `200 X 250`.
The size of `UIImageView` needs to be `200 X 250`.

How can I do this with auto-layout.

Comment: In your first example, shouldn't it be 250 x 250? 350 x 350 is larger than your max size.

Comment: Sorry Shawn, you are correct, it's my mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need three constraints here. One that maintains the aspect ratio, one that makes sure the width is no larger than the maximum, and one that makes sure the height is no larger than the maximum. As of August 2016, Interface Builder does not support constraints referencing other constraints, so – at a minimum – the aspect ratio constraint must be done in code.

The aspect ratio is the only one that takes any thinking. Let V_w and V_h be the width and height, respectively, of your image view. Let I_w and I_h be the width and height, respectively, of your image. Then, to maintain the image's aspect ratio, the following equation must remain true:

[image: V_w / V_h = I_w / I_h]

Or, equivalently:

[image: V_w = (I_w / I_h) * V_h]

Ok, looking good. Let's write some code. In this code, I assume you have `MAX_HEIGHT` and `MAX_WIDTH` defined earlier. **Note** that this code must target iOS 9.0 or later. If you're targeting an earlier version of iOS, see the block below.

```
// Constrain the desired aspect ratio
[imageView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:imageView.heightAnchor
                                    multiplier:aspectRatioMult].active = YES;

// Constrain height
[imageView.heightAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToConstant:MAX_HEIGHT].active = YES;

// Constrain width
[imageView.widthAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToConstant:MAX_WIDTH].active = YES;
```

---

For code targeting iOS versions before 9.0, `NSLayoutAnchor` is not available. Instead, you'll have to make due with `NSLayoutConstraint`.

```
CGFloat aspectRatioMult = (imageView.image.size.width / imageView.image.size.height);

// Constrain the desired aspect ratio
[imageView addConstraint:
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:imageView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                              multiplier:aspectRatioMult
                                constant:0]];

// Constrain height
[imageView addConstraints:
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[imageView(<=max)]"
                                          options:0
                                          metrics:@{@"max" : @(MAX_HEIGHT)}
                                            views:@{@"imageView" : imageView}]];

// Constrain width
[imageView addConstraints:
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[imageView(<=max)]"
                                          options:0
                                          metrics:@{@"max" : @(MAX_WIDTH)}
                                            views:@{@"imageView" : imageView}]];
```

Comment: How do I do that in Storyboard?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz You will not be able to create the proper constraints in Interface Builder, aka Storyboard. I've added a note saying so to the answer.

Comment: There is a mistake in code for iOS versions before 9.0. MAX_HEIGHT and MAX_WIDTH have to be swapped.